# Pinging / getting MAC address from IP, ignoring ARP cache

Tags: .net, windows, ip, arp

For the configuration software of a range of embedded devices, we have to find the devices by IP address. For any given IPv4 address, we need to

- find out the MAC address (because the MAC address can be filtered)
- find out if the device is reachable, i.e. ping it.

I'm unsure what the best way to do this is. At first, we tried to just call `SendARP` and it works quite well, but it uses only the cache if the IP address is already in there, and there does not seem a way to circumvent this (other than flushing the entire cache, which is a privileged operation). This means we have to do a second step and just ping the device (I think we should first ping it, then call `SendARP` if it was reachable), but that somehow seems to be a step too much if the device is reachable. Or will the correct address already be in the ARP cache if the ping was successful? The IP address might change its corresponding MAC address relatively often, because different devices are attached in a separate network, so I think we must force an actual ARP request.

The alternative I can think of is calling `ResolveNeighbor`/`ResolveIpNetEntry2`. At least the documentation of the latter seems to be what we need (clear ARP cache for this IP address and send an actual request), but it is only Vista or later. On XP, we would have to call `ResolveNeighbor`, which is simpler, but no longer documented. This involves checking for the right function (or just call `ResolveNeighbor` and if it fails, which it is documented to do on Vista or later, call `ResolveIpNetEntry2`).

I'm just not sure what the best way would be, or if I'm missing something. What would you recommend? Note that I'd also take a pure .NET solution if there is any ;)

**Update**:

It seems that ResolveNeighbor, despite being documented, does not exist on Windows XP, at least not in IPhlpapi.dll. Does that mean the functionality is not available on XP?

---

To get this straight, I'm neither designing the devices nor the deployment process. For this problem, just assume that

- all devices already have IP addresses and
- the computer is in the same subnet, but does not necessarily belong to the network (i.e. it is a tech's portable computer) and
- the IP address is known when the tool starts, i.e. the user can enter them or read them from a configuration file and
- the same computer, maybe even without restarting the tool, was used just a few seconds before to connect to an entirely different network with the very same IP addresses, for example a different building that is layed out the same.

This means I might have IP 192.168.0.100 in building A, which is MAC address A, and then connect the computer to building B, which also has an IP 192.168.0.100, but this time it's MAC address B. The user says "connect to 192.168.0.100" and we have to make sure that 192.168.0.100 is not only reachable, but is actually MAC B and not MAC A. I think that ResolveIpNetEntry2 would actually let me do this, but it's not available on Windows XP and there does not seem to be an alternative for this.

I'm not sure how else I can get this point across. The point is not how to discover or install the devices.

Comment: What is the embedded device and do you expect it to work in the enterprise environment?

Answer (score 1):

*The IP address might change its corresponding MAC address relatively often, because different devices are attached in a separate network, so I think we must force an actual ARP request.*

Huh?

*find out the MAC address (because the MAC address can be filtered)*

To what ends?

I think you need to take a step back, because right now I think you're asking *"I need to get the MAC address of an IP address on a different subnet"*. This is not possible.

It sounds your trying to design software to manage network-attached devices and you are looking for a service discovery solution.

---

Update after comment:
*It's a software to configure and update networked building automation controllers. A lot of these devices will be attached to and removed from a tech's computer. There may be multiple devices with the same IP address attached to the tech's computer (one after another, not at the same time), so we can't rely on the ARP cache to figure out the MAC address. The devices will be on the same subnet as the computer (i.e. the computer will be put into the devices' subnet to connect to them). If you know another method to reliantly a) ping the device and b) get its MAC address, I'm thankful :)*

So your process is two step?

- A staging process where devices are attached to the controlling computer, are discovered and configured
- At a later point in time, the devices will be deployed and attached to the same subnet with the controlling computer.

The devices are shipped pre-configured with the same IP address?

If you are able to ping a device on the same subnet, the arp cache should have the correct mac address. However, if the scenario means that there's the possibility of multiple devices plugged in competing for the same IP address, you are going to have problems.

If you are expecting to be able to sell these devices into campus environments then you can't rely on all of the devices being on the same subnet or being in the same subnet as the controller. Subnets may not be available between buildings.

My first suggestion for the design would be to have the devices acquire their IP addresses via DHCP and include the name or address of the controller(s) as a DHCP option. The controller being implemented as a "server". The devices could pick up their configurations from the controller. The devices could register with the controller while they are operational. Many options for introducing security with signing of configurations. Certificate authenticated comms, etc, etc.

---

Update after updated question.

*I'm not sure how else I can get this point across.* Explaining the scenario is a good start.

Saying that *A lot of these devices will be attached to and removed from a tech's computer.* is a peculiar way of describing what you've elaborated on since.

I'll stop trying to guess what you're doing and I'll stop trying to save you from yourself.

Yes, if you can successfully ping an IP address on the same subnet then the ARP cache *should* contain the current MAC address for that IP address. I'd suggest you test this for each operating system you use as there may be vagaries regarding access to the caches.

Comment: It's a software to configure and update networked building automation controllers. A lot of these devices will be attached to and removed from a tech's computer. There may be multiple devices with the same IP address attached to the tech's computer (one after another, not at the same time), so we can't rely on the ARP cache to figure out the MAC address. The devices will be on the same subnet as the computer (i.e. the computer will be put into the devices' subnet to connect to them). If you know another method to reliably a) ping the device and b) get its MAC address, I'm thankful :)

Comment: I updated my question, maybe this makes the problem more clear. However, you say that *If you are able to ping a device on the same subnet, the arp cache should have the correct mac address* - does that mean that if I do an ICMP ping to the controller and afterwards call SendARP, I will reliably get the correct MAC address, even if the IP belonged to another MAC address just a few moments before? (Note that the devices do not change addresses randomly, it's always done manually (; )

Comment: If you do a ping to the controller and the ping succeeds and afterwards you get the MAC from the ARP cache it will have the latests MAC of the adress that replied the ping so it has to be the good one.

Comment: @MattH: I'm sorry that you seem to think I'm just ignorant ;) I appreciate the time you invested, but there is really nothing I can change about the process I'm implementing. It just has to do The Right Thing[tm]. I just tried the Ping, then SendARP thing on my system, worked pretty well with exchanging devices with the same IP address, but different MAC address. If it also works fine on XP and x86 Windows 7, I think I have my solution.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Glad you've found something that works. *you seem to think I'm just ignorant* - Nothing wrong with ignorance, this is a question and answer site. If you had more understanding IP and Ethernet, you wouldn't be asking this question. I'm often on or near the receiving end of poorly designed network-attached devices and it's surprising how much networking is poorly understood and how much is poorly implemented. I attempt to influence if an opportunity appears.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past in a similar situation was to Ping to the required address and then execute from the C# applitacion the arp command to get the desired MAC.

Each time you need to access a MAC you refresh it executing this process.